# Get Value of Selected Codemirror If I have Multiple on Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

## I have multiple codemirror on same page i want to get value of selected cpdemirror how can i do that.

I have created a function to make codemirror from different textarea. This is the code below which i am using.

I am trying to make editor like [codepen](https://codepen.io)

```
function CMeditor(id, mode){
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(id), {
    theme: "monokai",
    mode: mode,
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
  });
  editor.setSize("50%", "100%");
}

CMeditor("actual-html-code", "htmlmixed");
CMeditor("actual-css-code", "css");
CMeditor("actual-js-code", "javascript");
```

You can also suggest me the code to update textarea of each codemirror div.

Answer (score 1):

Go through `each` editors wrapper, find the editor, and either get or set the value.

If you have your content or "code" in the textarea, then you will need to set the editors value by using `editor.setValue()`, then use `editor.getValue()`.

To find the mode you could add a data-attribute to each wrapper, then set the mode in the initialization.

**html:**

```
<div class="wrapper" data-mode="htmlmixed">
    <textarea class="editor"></textarea>
<div>
<div class="wrapper" data-mode="css">
    <textarea class="editor"></textarea>
<div>
<div class="wrapper" data-mode="javascript">
    <textarea class="editor"></textarea>
<div>
```

**js:**

```
var editorOptions = {
  theme: "monokai",
  lineNumbers: true,
  lineWrapping: true,
};

$('.wrapper').each(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(self.find(".editor")[0], editorOptions);
  self[0].editor = editor;
  editor.save();

  // set the mode
  var mode = self.attr('data-mode');
  editor.setOption("mode", mode);

  // find textarea value and set editor value:
  var text = self.find('.editor').text();
  editor.setValue(text);

  // to get the editors value:
  editor.getValue();
});
```